# How to rebind a click event to a hidden Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a BOOTSTRAP modal that is called from a button.  On the modal, there is a form with a popover.  I have the code working for it to show the popover and then hide it if the user clicks off the popover.  But if the user then clicks the link with the popover again, nothing happens.  No event fires.  How do I rebind the click event to the link?  Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.cvv-popover', function(e) {
        $(this).popover('show').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#renewal-form', function(e) {
                $('.popover').each(function () {
                    // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
                    if (!$(this).is(e.target && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)) {
                        $('span.cvv-popover').popover('hide')
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML

Comment: Could you rephrase your question ? I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See the answer from amit_g here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695180/closing-bootstrap-popover-when-user-clicks-outside-popover?rq=1.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because bootsrap's `.popover` instantiates the popover command when you call it, and because each time you click on the `.cvv-popover` you attach a `body.on('click')` listener, I believe the reason you're not seeing the popover after the first click is because you've got a `.popover` and a `.on('click')` buildup--meaning that after the first click the last code called each time will be `.popover('hide')`. In order to fix this I'd recommend using bootstrap's built-in selector option and utilizing jQuery's `.off` method.

First just call `.popover` from the body element, but specifying the selector as `.cvv-popover`:

```
$('body').popover({ selector: '.cvv-popover' });
```

This instantiates the popover js on all of your `.cvv-popover` elements regardless of when they were added to the DOM.

Then, in order to remove the popover by clicking anywhere else on the DOM attach a listener to bootstraps `shown.bs.popover`:

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.popover', '.cvv-popover', function(e) {
    var _this = this;
    $('body').on('click.hidePopover', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('popover-content')) {
            hidePopover(_this);
        }
    });
});

var hidePopover = function(popover) {
    $(popover).popover('hide');
    $('body').off('.hidePopover');
};
```

This code waits for a popover to be shown and when it is, it adds a click listener event to the `body`. The click listener asserts that the element clicked is not a popover itself and, as long as it isn't a popover, calls the `hidePopover()` function, passing in the currently visible popover. The `hidePopover()` function takes a popover as an argument and proceeds to hide that popover and then remove the `click.hidePopover` listener event from the body so that the `.popover('hide')` call no longer exists when clicking on the body. Thus, the popover is only hidden once and only after it is visible, allowing for the expected functionality.

[Here is the JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hz4G/3/)

*Answer has been updated to use bootstrap*

*JS Fiddle adds a second `.cvv-popover` to the dom dynamically so that you can be sure the code works for dynamically populated elements*

Comment: Also, scoping the `body` tag, compared to the `document` isn't necessary, just my preferred way. If you use `document` just make sure to replace all instances above of `'body'` with `document`.

Comment: That's not Bootstrap.

Comment: My apologies. I wrote a general JS answer assuming it'd be easily translatable to bootstrap, but I realize now it wasn't quite. I'm going to edit my answer with a better one that specifically addresses bootstrap.

Comment: Answer updated. Lot's of info in the answer but the JS Fiddle should quickly give you a working code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo :

```
if (!$(this).is(e.target && [...].length === 0))
               ^                              ^
         this paren ...          is closed here
```

If it really is a `Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V` from your code, you should fix it.